# D3. Variable declaration in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There is declared variable inside the anonymous function, which when returns that variable. Problem is that I can't seem to use that variable, because when I try to return it `firebug` says, that: `TypeError: myData is undefined` .

---

This is my code:

```
select("circle")
    .transition()
    .attr("r", function(d) { 
                var myData = d3.select(this).datum();
                return myData[0];
    } )
    .duration(1000);
```

That `return myData[0];` does indeed return first array element, however my animation takes less than 1 second which means that `.duration(1000);` doesn't get called, because there is an error in that `return myData[0];` , which is kind of puzzling.

That's how I attach data to that circle prior the attempt to animate it:

```
  var valuesMatrix = [];
  valuesMatrix[0] = [35, 21, 45, 71, 51, 32];

  d3.selectAll("circle")
    .data(valuesMatrix);
```

Why `return myData[0];` is considered like undeclared even though it returns valid value.

---

Update. Press on rectangle to see circle animation:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                  .attr("width", 200)
                                  .attr("height", 200);

svgContainer.append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", 40)
                        .attr("cy", 40)
                        .attr("r", 20);

var valuesMatrix = [];
  valuesMatrix[0] = [35, 21, 45, 71, 51, 32];

svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
    .data(valuesMatrix);

svgContainer.append("rect")
                   .attr("x", 90)
                   .attr("y", 10)
                   .attr("width", 80)
                   .attr("height", 20)
                   .on("click", function(d) {
                          var selectedGroups = d3.selectAll("circle")
                              .transition()
                              .attr("r", function(d) { 
                                    var myData = d3.select(this).datum();
                                    // return d[0];
                                    return myData[0];
                                } )
                          .duration(2000);
                     });
```

This Code is jsfiddle - ready.
It seems to be working

http://jsfiddle.net/regpast123/axkbLp45/2/

Comment: can you put this up on a fiddle.

Comment: You need only `return d[0];`. The error message suggests that you haven't bound any data to the element that you're selecting.

Comment: I've just uploaded it on jsfiddle and it seems to be working, something is wrong with my environment then. You can find link in description

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff  that was the case. You can write it as an answer - I would accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message suggests that you haven't bound any data to the element you're selecting. Furthermore, you can simplify the code:

```
.attr("r", function(d) { return d[0]; });
```